# Unity ShaderGraph Temporal Blur

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, blur, temporal, shader-graph

I'm working on a mobile game, and I want to add an effect when the player hits a speed up. My idea is to create some kind of temporal blur using a shadergraph, in full screen pass renderer (available with URP).

The main idea is to use a URP Sample Buffer node (Blitsource), and if it's possible to convert/store them in a sample texture 2d. Multiple sample textures should be needed, as they show the screen from different time. After that, we connect the different sample textures with blend nodes, with different opacity values (the oldest time texture get the lowest value).

So my question is if we can store or convert the URP Sample Buffer data at a specific time, and use it like a sample texture, so I can blend them?

Thank you.

Regards, Samih.